# Debug Flash Media Server

Tags: actionscript, flash-builder, flash-media-server

Is there any method to do live debugging on Flash Media Server, i.e. examine current variables, set breakpoints, watch expressions?  I'm using Flash Builder 4 and am fantasizing about something akin to "Attach to Process" in Visual Studio.

The endless cycle of [trace statements -> server restart -> client state reset -> read log -> repeat] is ruining my disposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such tool for FMS. But I can suggest to use:

1. FMS Admin console to read logs. http://www.flashcomguru.com/console/index.cfm
2. Unload application via console instead of server restart. This will cut time. Application will load again on first connect.